# Detect the bottom of a WebBrowser Page in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a xaml page in which I have used a webbrowser control.I need to scroll down to the web page and once the bottom is reached,I have to enable a button.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There's two part to this. The first is to detect, in Javascript, the moment when the browser reaches the bottom of the page. The second is to forward the event to the C# code.

Say you ask your `WebBrowser` control to navigate to a given page. First, in the C# code, subscribe to the `Navigated` event to inject the proper Javascript code:

```
private void WebBrowser_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    const string Script = @"window.onscroll = function() {
        if ((window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
            window.external.notify('bottom');
        }
    };";

    this.WebBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", Script);
}
```

This Javascript code uses the `window.external.notify` method to notify the C# code. To receive the notification, you need to subscribe to the `ScriptNotify` event of the `WebBrowser`:

```
private void WebBrowser_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Value == "bottom")
    {
        // Reached the bottom of the page
    }
}
```